# Rails I18n Backend with MongoDB/Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, mongodb, mongoid

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this (http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends) with MongoDB/Mongoid? My question is primarily about the initializer.rb file.

The docs of [Mongo-I18n](https://github.com/aulizko/mongo-i18n) on github suggests the following using its 'MongoI18n::Store.new' method:

```
  collection = Mongo::Connection.new['my_app_related_db'].collection('i18n')
  I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(MongoI18n::Store.new(collection)
```

But how to do this if you don't want to use their plugin? Is there something like a Mongo::Store method?

Answer (score 1):

I just did this exact same thing, except that I had trouble installing Mongo-I18n, because it has a dependency on a very old version of MongoDB.

To get around this, I copied the code from [here](https://github.com/aulizko/mongo-i18n/blob/master/lib/mongo-i18n/store.rb) into `lib/mongo_i18n.rb`.

You were on the right track with your initializer though, if you're using Mongoid - the best way forward is to do this:

```
require 'mongo_i18n'
collection = Mongoid.database.collection('i18n')
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(MongoI18n::Store.new(collection))
```

Which tells the I18n backend to use a new collection (called i18n), but in the same database as the rest of your application.

Make sure you delete the Mongo_I18n gem out of your gemfile and run `bundle` before starting your server again.

You can access your store directly using:

```
I18n.backend.store
```

But to make it a little cleaner, I added this method to my I18n library:

```
# mongo_i18n.rb
def self.store
  collection = Mongoid.database.collection('i18n')
  MongoI18n::Store.new
end
```

So that I can access the store directly with:

```
MongoI18n.store
```

Comment: thanks, the server is starting without complaints. but how would you retrieve/access the translations in the index view and controller? Using TRANSLATION_STORE as a constant doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some additional details about accessing the I18n store. I also fixed a typo in the original code :)

Comment: USING TRANSLATION_STORE (rails casts) [code]                           COLLECTION = Mongo::Connection.new['tflocale'].collection('i18n')
TRANSLATION_STORE = MongoI18n::Store.new(COLLECTION)
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(TRANSLATION_ST

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly like theTRON said, except that instead of require 'mongo_i18n' I added whole class MongoI18n::Store definition from Mongo_i18n gem directly to mongo initializer. It not such a big deal, because whole MongoI18n::Store is 41 lines long. [Look here](https://github.com/aulizko/mongo-i18n/blob/master/lib/mongo-i18n/store.rb), why make dependancy from 41 lines gem ?